# How to prevent a user from using space in a tablespace?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, tablespace

I tried the following commands,but i can still insert into the table on appts. Why?

```
MICHAEL@orcl@SQL> alter user michael quota 0M on appts;

User altered.

MICHAEL@orcl@SQL> select tablespace_name,max_bytes from user_ts_quotas;

TABLESPACE_NAME               ,       MAX_BYTES
------------------------------,----------------
APPTS                         ,               0


MICHAEL@orcl@SQL> select tablespace_name,table_name from user_tables;

TABLESPACE_NAME               ,TABLE_NAME
------------------------------,------------------------------
APPTS                         ,TEST_D
....


MICHAEL@orcl@SQL> insert into test_d values(292,'Test',500,2100);

1 row created.
```

Comment: Any table created in oracle has some minimum size (couple of bytes). So it can contain several hundreds of rows without extending the segment. Try the same experiment but generate a few thousand rows.

Comment: Try creating a new table, or have a pre-existing table with deferred segment creation. The quota will be applied when a new segment is needed, as haki suggests.

Answer (score 1):

What about using ALTER TABLESPACE to make it read only?  You could enter:

```
ALTER TABLESPACE APPTS READ ONLY
```